# Why update query is not working as expected in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to replace some sentences from wordpress posts content using phpMyadmin
here is my update query

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE (`post_content`,  'Example Routes:',  'Routes:') WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%Example Routes:%';
```

but it says "0 rows affected".

I have run a select query that have the same condition to ensure that there is resutls and I have so many resutls
here is the select query

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%Example Routes:%';
```

Please note that both query conditions is the same as what I am updating my condition is "LIKE '%Example Routes:%'" and the update is "REPLACE (`post_content`,  'Example Routes:',  'Routes:')".

Any idea why the update is giving me 0 rows affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and working around I figured it out, the select query give results because the `LIKE` operator is not case sensitive but Replace is, so I needed to replace 'Example Routes:' to 'Example routes:' in the replace function which is a bit tricky.

I ended up using this query which works for me

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'Example routes:','Routes:')
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%Example Routes:%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the space between `REPLACE` and the opening parenthesis:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,  'Example Routes:',  'Routes:') 
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%Example Routes:%';
```

By default, you aren't allowed to include whitespace between function names and their parentheses: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html